# Why do I get "not a tty" when running "tty" in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, centos

How come, after I launch CentOS as a Docker container, when I run `tty` I get:

```
# tty
not a tty
```

What's the reason for `not a tty`?

Comment: ...probably that your stdin isn't a TTY? (A tty has a bunch of out-of-band interaction sysctls that aren't available over other file descriptors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker run` does not simulate a TTY unless told to do so with `-t`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/foreground